# Cambio de caracteres en una Palabra en C++

Tags: c++, caracteres

En C++, programa que pida meter 3 palabras ( Cualquiera )despues cambie la primera letra De cada Palabra por una letra Distinta. Lo estoy haciendo con crear funciones pero en el espacio del primer IF donde se ubica la letra (a) pero no se que logica hacer para que el usuario decida que letra o palabra quiera escribir en vez de solo cambiar solamente cuando se ponga la letra a.

```
Include<iostream>

Using name space std;

Char cambio (char c){
If(c == 'a'){
C= '+'; }

If(c == 'd'){
C= ':'};

Return c;
}

Void gestion(char *v){
While(*v != '\0'){
*v = cambio(*v);
*v++;
}
}

Int main(){

Char *frase = new char [150];
Cout <<"ingrese 3 palabras: " 
<<endl;
Cin.getline(frase,100);
Cout<<frase<<endl;

Gestion(frase);

Cout<<frase<<endl;
Delete frase;
Return 0;
}
```

Comment: hola amigo parece que haz tenido problemas con el copiado/pegado de tu codigo fuente, en C++ no se admiten mayusculas para las palabras clave de este mismo(y parece ser que el documento de word te lo ha formateado a empezar con mayusuculas con cada salto de linea). Te sugiero que lo cambies, si es que lo tienes asi en tu codigo fuente.

Answer (score 1):

> programa que pida meter 3 palabras

Es decir, necesitamos un bucle y, dentro del mismo, pedimos una palabra:

```
for( int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    std::string palabra;
    std::cin >> palabra;
}
```

> despues cambie la primera letra De cada Palabra por una letra Distinta

Le pides al usuario que introduzca un caracter adicional y haces el reemplazo:

```
for( int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    std::string palabra;
    std::cin >> palabra;

    std::cin >> c;
    palabra[0] = c;

    std::cout << palabra << '\n';        
}
```

Claro que también puedes hacer el reemplazo sin variables intermedias:

```
for( int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    std::string palabra;
    std::cin >> palabra;

    std::cin >> palabra[0];

    std::cout << palabra << '\n';        
}
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando [Aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sHlQ1HYVlTWSmlCR)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto... no sé que compidor usas pero en el mio los tipos se escriben en minusculas. Probablamente debas cambiar eso para que te funcione.

```
int main()
{
    char *palabra1 = new char [50];
    char *palabra2 = new char [50];
    char *palabra3 = new char [50];

    cout<<"ingresa palabra1"<<endl;
    cin>>palabra1;
    cout<<"ingresa palabra2"<<endl;
    cin>>palabra2;
    cout<<"ingresa palabra3"<<endl;
    cin>>palabra3;

    char letra1;
    char letra2;
    char letra3;

    cout<<"ingresa letra1"<<endl;
    cin>>letra1;
    cout<<"ingresa letra2"<<endl;
    cin>>letra2;
    cout<<"ingresa letra3"<<endl;
    cin>>letra3;

    palabra1[0] = letra1;
    palabra2[0] = letra2;
    palabra3[0] = letra3;

    cout<<"*******************************************"<<endl;
    cout<< palabra1 <<" "<< palabra3 <<" "<< palabra3 <<endl;
    cout<<"*******************************************"<<endl;

    delete[] palabra1;
    delete[] palabra2;
    delete[] palabra3;

    return 0;
}
```

Dale caña!! A veces las cosas son mas simples de lo que parecen!! Saludos y suerte!!

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la ayuda voy a probar.

Comment: De nada!! A mi me han ayudado un montón aquí también. Ya es hora de que empiece a devolver los favores que me han hecho... Si te sirve el programa ponme un like ahi arriba... no sé para que sirve pero me hace ilusión XD... Un Saludo Israel!!